# Error HH13: Your Hardhat project uses typescript, but ts-node is not installed

Tags: web3js, hardhat

i just try to run test command with my project which i can't disclose file . hardhat showing below error

```
Error HH13: Your Hardhat project uses typescript, but ts-node is not installed.

Please run: npm install --save-dev ts-node

HardhatError: HH13: Your Hardhat project uses typescript, but ts-node is not installed.

Please run: npm install --save-dev ts-node
    at loadTsNode (/home/vasu/Desktop/Audit/vmex/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/typescript-support.ts:54:11)
    at main (/home/vasu/Desktop/Audit/vmex/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/cli/cli.ts:184:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vasu/Desktop/Audit/vmex/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/cli/cli.ts:380:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vasu/Desktop/Audit/vmex/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/cli/bootstrap.ts:16:1)
```

After i  installed ts-node by this command  `npm install --save-dev ts-node` also it showing same error .